# Hosting Grails Application

Tags: java, grails, ubuntu-server

I have a grails application which is running in http://localhost:8080/appname. I want to Deploy it on www.abc.anything.us. I  build a war with production `grails.serverURL=www.abc.anything.us`. Copied the war to `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/`, but the url not work. Need a document of about publishing grails app to own host.